# Create horizontal collapsible accordion with pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I have 4 divisions as follows :[image]

On hovering the 1st element it becomes :[image]

ie I changed the CSS of the next elements on hovering the 1st using '~' selector.

```
/* hover on 1 */
#pillar1:hover {
width: 64%;
}
#pillar1:hover ~ #pillar2{
width: 12%;
}
#pillar1:hover ~ #pillar3{
width: 12%;
}
#pillar1:hover ~ #pillar4{
width: 12%;
}
```

But on hovering the next divisions, using the code

```
/* hover on 2 */
#pillar2:hover {
width: 64%;
}
#pillar2:hover ~ #pillar1{
width: 12%;
}
#pillar2:hover ~ #pillar3{
width: 12%;
}
#pillar2:hover ~ #pillar4{
width: 12%;
}
```

the transition is not happening.
**HTML**

```
 <section class="pillars">

<div id="pillar1"></div>
    <div id="pillar2"></div>
<div id="pillar3"></div>
<div id="pillar4"></div>
</section>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: please post your HTML too

Comment: The `~` selector is only the following siblings https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

Comment: The reason that this doesn't work is that the ~ operator selects elements fitting the right-hand selector appearing after elements fitting the left-hand selector (with the same parent). It works for pillar1 because the other pillars all do appear after it, but not for any of the others. Using ~ isn't a great idea though, as there are simpler ways of doing this.

Comment: @gandaliter how can I do it?

Comment: See my answer for one possible way.

Answer (score 8):

When you use `~` it will select elements which are followed after the element which is hovered, so just one property will do the job for you i.e

```
display: flex;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mNMTg/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
    display: flex;
}

.wrap > div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 33%;
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    -webkit-transition: flex .5s;
    transition: flex .5s;
}

.wrap > div:hover {
    flex: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can have some **workaround** like this:

```
.pillars > div {
  width: 25%;
  float:left;
  ...
}
.pillars:hover > div {
  width:12%;
}
.pillars > div:hover {
  width: 64%;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/Q5h6q/1/)

The reason we have to do it with a workaround is we can't traverse back using CSS3 selector, that is when you hover on a list item, you **can't** traverse back the previous list items to set their width to `12%`. However, hovering on list item also triggers hovering on the parent container. So we can make it work by setting the `width:12%` to all the list items on hovering the parent.

Comment: this might be the most obvious solution but it actually have a problem: browsers sometimes fail to round values and the result will be the last element going on a second row while transition is running

Comment: Yea thats the behavior I notified

Comment: yes, hovering between the list items quickly can create a gap (at last) due to the transition time. We should use the modern solution with flex layout as given by Mr. Alien or the compatible solution using table layout as given by SW4.

Answer (score 1):

### [Updated: Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/Q5h6q/2/)

HTML

```
<div class='expanded'></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
div {
    float:left;
    width:12%;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background:lightgrey;
    transition:width 100ms ease-in;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.expanded {
    width:64%;
}
```

jQuery

```
$("div").hover(

function () {
    $("div").removeClass("expanded");
    $(this).addClass("expanded");
}, function () {
    $("div").removeClass("expanded");
    $("div:first").addClass("expanded");
});
```

---

### [Alternative Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/mNMTg/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="table">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
}
.table div {
    display:table-cell;
    width:12%;
    border:1px solid red;
    background:lightgrey;
    transition:width 100ms ease-in;
}
.table div:hover {
    width:64%;
}
```

Comment: the OP has 4 divs and looks like the total width should be `100%`, so each one is `25%` in normal state

Comment: total width should be 100% everytime

Comment: well not really, see that spaces between the divs in the example? if he sets total width to 100% it will cause an overflow. should calc(25% - space)

Comment: The implementation has been udpated

Answer (score 1):

Similar solution to those already posted, but imho the only actually *rock solid*

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zK2pc/)

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/people/5/" style="display:block;"/></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/people/5/" style="display:block;"/></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/people/5/" style="display:block;"/></div>
</div>

.wrap
{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

.wrap > div {
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px red solid;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100px;
    transition:width 1s;
    width:33.333%;
}

.wrap > div:hover {
    width: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a wrapper div:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div style="background-color: blue;"></div>
  <div style="background-color: red;"></div>
  <div style="background-color: green;"></div>
  <div style="background-color: purple;"></div>
</div>
```

and then in the css:

```
.wrapper div {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
.wrapper:hover div {
  width: 12%;
}
.wrapper div:hover {
  width: 64%;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
```

JSFiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ax6xX/)