# CSS two column layout on hover increase width

Tags: html, css

I want to have a row with 2 columns (both fluid), when I hover an element in one of the column, it will reveal content by horizontal slide, this should make the column wider and hence the other one less wide. Is this possible in pure CSS?

```
[ Left column fluid (elementX)][Right column fluid]
```

On mouse over of (elementX), we'll get something like this:

```
[ Left column fluid (elementXxxxxxx)][Right col...]
```

Here is an example that might illustrate it better: 
[image]

Is this doable in pure CSS? If yes, how?

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hvh29/3/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: table-cell;` or you can use `display: flex;` as well, so I'll contribute flex way as its latest, and much lenient compared to `display: table-cell;` method which was old way to achieve so...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WuTF4/)

```
.wrap {
    display: flex;
}

.wrap .col {
    min-height: 100px;
    background: #eee;
    width: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}

div.wrap > div:nth-of-type(1) {
    background: #aaa;
}

div.wrap > div:hover {
    width: 70%;    
}
```

I've answered a similar one over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23493318/1542290)

Comment: for consideration, regarding sliding, typically it looks better if you can play with the margin or position of the elements.  using the width tends to resize/re-wrap the contents.  In this case maybe play with the zindex as well since your talking about side by side columns

Comment: @fnostro Yes indeed but OP haven't shared his views over that so if he clarifies I'll edit my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible for example for left column to be fixed width, and right column be flexible. And when I hover col left, it becomes width auto with a max?

Comment: @Mr.Alien: apologies I wasn't more clear, the comment was for denislexic to consider, not meant as a consideration for a rewrite of your answer.  Your answer is right on target.

Comment: I added an image to illustrate a bit better what I'm looking forward. Thanks again.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that sliding position is better than sliding, will change some of my code :)

Comment: @denislexic I saw your element, so why not the circles push your text straight away?

Comment: @Mr.Alien I actually have a lot of different elements on that line (custom tick box, text and tags with wrappers). Is that even possible, I'll share a more precise example in jsfiddle in a minute.

Comment: Here is a more precise layout of what I'm looking for. But as you can see, I can't even get the blocks to align. And ideally the tags would align right... http://jsfiddle.net/hvh29/5/

Comment: And obviously the slide to reveal would ideally be smooth...but no idea :S Thanks for you help. http://jsfiddle.net/hvh29/6/